# Best practices for validating wcf endpoint on client with/without SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, wcf-endpoint

I tried to catch all exception of wcf sercue with/without SSL/TLS or endpoint, something like this:

```
try
        {
            ServiceReference.ServiceClient serviceClient = new ChartLogicServiceClient();
            serviceClient.Open();
            serviceClient.Login("", "", "");
        }
        catch (SecurityNegotiationException negotiationException)
        {
            // Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost'.
            throw;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException argumentException)
        {
            // transport wrong config : The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
            //if (argumentException.Message == "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter name: via")
            throw;
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException messageSecurityException)
        {
            // transport wrong config: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
            //- HTTP Request Error
            if (messageSecurityException.InnerException.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.")
            {
                throw;
            }
            else if (messageSecurityException.InnerException.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (404) Forbidden.")
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException endpointNotFoundException)
        {
            // no endpoint was found or IIS on server was turned off

        }
```

Can i check the available of wcf service without calling any method ( i tried Open() but not work at all)?
Not sure i catch all cases of exception from WCF service? My purpose is if client got wcf exception with SSL/TSL or no endpoint, i should run a small utility console to fix app.config on client to map with wcf endpoint and .
I really need your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try to connect to the URL of the service and check the response code. Maybe not the best way, but it should work. e.g.

```
GET mysite/myservice.svc
```

and check for the HTTP status code.

Comment: thanks, i used GET on WebRequest, WebResponse and it works fine